# Draw lines with Clojure

Tags: clojure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [draw line with anti-aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475380/draw-line-with-anti-aliasing)

I want to draw lines and circles on screen with Clojure, how to do it? can someone paste some sample codes here?

Another problem, I define a Map:

```
 (def {:a 4, :b 5, :c 6}, i try to change it to be {:a 1, :b 99, :c 3},
```

how to do it?

Comment: Exact duplicate from the same user.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the seesaw library, it gives a good Clojure friendly model for many types of GUIs inlcuding shapes.

https://gist.github.com/1441520