# Arc stroke smoothness

Tags: clojure, processing, clojurescript, quil

I am currently making a clock with quil and [Daniel Shiffman's video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4RyStef-gY&t=517s), but I have a trouble drawing `arc` that the arc drew the stroke little bad than `line`.

[image: Clock Image]

I don't know what's the problem or maybe my code is wrong or something to create an `arc`, so, this is my code.

```
(defn draw-state [state]
  ; Clear the sketch by filling it with light-grey color.
  (q/background 150)

  (let [max-scale-h (- 1 (/ 1 12))
        max-scale-m (- 1 (/ 1 60))
        max-scale-s (- 1 (/ 1 60))]
    (let
      [
        h (q/map-range
           (if (> (q/hour) 12) (- (q/hour) 12) (q/hour)) 0 11 0 max-scale-h)
        m (q/map-range (q/minute) 0 59 0 max-scale-m)
        s (q/map-range (q/seconds) 0 59 0 max-scale-s)

        half-width (/ (q/width) 2)
        half-height (/ (q/height) 2)
        ]

      ;; let body
      (q/translate half-width half-height)
      (q/rotate (* -1 q/HALF-PI))

      (q/stroke-weight 8)
      (q/no-fill)

      (let [angle (* q/TWO-PI h)]
        (q/stroke 255 100 150)
        (q/arc 0 0 300 300 0 angle)

        (q/push-style)
        (q/rotate angle)
        (q/line 0 0 60 0)
        (q/pop-style))

      (let [angle (* q/TWO-PI m)]
        (q/stroke 150 100 255)
        (q/arc 0 0 280 280 0 angle)

        (q/push-style)
        (q/rotate angle)
        (q/line 0 0 70 0)
        (q/pop-style))

      (let [angle (* q/TWO-PI s)]
        (q/stroke 150 255 100)
        (q/arc 0 0 260 260 0 angle)

        (q/push-style)
        (q/rotate angle)
        (q/line 0 0 128 0)
        (q/pop-style)
        ))))
```

**UPDATE**

I added `(q/smooth)` in setup as [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475380/draw-line-with-anti-aliasing), but it still same.

```
(defn setup []
  (q/smooth)
  (q/frame-rate 30)
  (q/color-mode :rgb)
  )
```

**UPDATE**
I tried to use smooth in `processing` and it works but no change with the web version.

Left for web and Right for Processing

**UPDATE**

`Sad Developer` create an issue in github to follow [the problem](https://github.com/quil/quil/issues/229)

[image: Differences]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [draw line with anti-aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475380/draw-line-with-anti-aliasing)

Comment: @cfrick :  I added smooth but it still the same

Comment: I've filed an issue on the GitHub (https://github.com/quil/quil/issues/229) because it does not happen in Processing.js or in JVM-based Quil.

Comment: @SadDeveloper : Thank you

Comment: @Ampersanda See the discussion on GitHub - jaggedness is caused by the change in processing.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading to quil 3.0.0 will resolve this issue. Quil now uses p5js instead of processing.js which does not have the problem with jagged lines. See http://quil.info/sketches/show/snippet_arc